# Passing Parameter to MDX Query through ADOMD in C#

Tags: c#, ssas, ssas-2012

Iam building an webapp. I am attempting to retrieve to pull data from an SSAS cube through MDX query in C#.(from WebAPI).

Can any one please share a sample of code to how to pass a parameter in MDX Query through C#?

Comment: I don't think you can parameterize MDX queries in ADOMD the way you can with ADO + SQL.   I think you have to build the string, concatenating variables, and then execute the string without parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This is about the simplest example:
You can wrap a parameter in StrToSet if you need to use a set expression.

```
var connection = new AdomdConnection(...);
var command = new AdomdCommand(@"
            SELECT StrToMember(@Measure) ON 0
            FROM [SomeCube]
            ", connection);

command.Parameters.Add(new AdomdParameter("Measure", "[Measures].[Foo]"));
var cellset = command.ExecuteCellSet();
```